# Mule Cloudhub - disable custom logging deployment parameter

Tags: mulesoft, cloudhub

I am writing my mule application's cloud hub logs to external  Rapid7 (log entries), by following this article. [Integrate with Your Logging System Using Log4j](https://docs.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/custom-log-appender#:%7E:text=From%20Anypoint%20Platform%2C%20select%20Runtime%20Manager.%20Click%20Applications,In%20the%20Settings%20page%2C%20click%20Disable%20CloudHub%20logs%3A)

To enable custom logging, I have checked "Disable cloudhub logs" manually in the run time manager in cloudhub portal, as shown below.
[image]

**But every time I deploy the application Via Jenkins build pipeline, this gets unchecked. I searched for deployment parameter to set this, but couldn't find one.**

I found API option to set this, but I need to call this as soon as application is deployed, and the api call will redeploy the application. https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-disable-CloudHub-logging-using-API

**Is there any better solution for this?**

Runtime Version: 4.4.0

Comment: You deploy how exactly? Using Maven? Share the configuration of the Mule Maven Plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Mule Maven Plugin be sure that the configuration disableCloudHubLogs is set to true. Otherwise it may be reseting to false which according to the documentation is false.

Documentation reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/deploy-to-cloudhub#cloudhub-deploy-reference

Comment: Thanks for the document reference. It worked.